# How to add data from array/Object to the HTML drop down menu using JSON and Fetch/Async Await

Tags: javascript, html, json, drop-down-menu, fetch-api

I want to add the name of the cat to the drop-down menu. I can access properties and their values. But, when I try to enter/put those values in the menu, only the last value is getting store. I am assuming that it is (code - Function accessArray) replacing the current value once it loops through the whole thing.
[console.log(data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06fGC.png)

data.name has the list of the cat names.
[console.log(element.name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar2K6.png)

I want to create a list so that I can have names of all the cats in the drop-down menu.
[drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kepY3.jpg)

Here is the link of public API that I am using - https://docs.thecatapi.com/api-reference/breeds/breeds-list

```
async function start(){
   try{
    const response = await fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log (data);
    filterData(data);
   }catch (e){
    console.log("Error : "+ e);
   }
}
start();


function filterData (data){
    data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.name);
        acessArray(element.name);
    });
}


function acessArray(data){
    document.getElementById("catList").innerHTML = `
    <select>
        <option value="Choose a cat">Choose a cat</option>
        <option> ${data} </option>            
    </select>
    `;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want your code do but if it just `<option>` then you will figure it out.

Each time you are set this
`document.getElementById("catList").innerHTML = '<select>...</select>'`
you overwrite the last input.

Look the code and replace what you need.

```js
async function start(){
   try{
    const response = await fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log (data);
    filterData(data);
   }catch (e){
    console.log("Error : "+ e);
   }
}
start();


function filterData (data){
    document.getElementById("catList").innerHTML = ''; // clear the list
    data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.name);
        acessArray(element.name);
    });
}


function acessArray(data){
    // This will add a <select> over another <select> and so on
    document.getElementById("catList").innerHTML += `
    <select>
        <option value="Choose a cat">Choose a cat</option>
        <option> ${data} </option>            
    </select>
    `;
}
```

What I think it should do:

```js
async function start(){
   try{
    const response = await fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log (data);
    filterData(data);
   }catch (e){
    console.log("Error : "+ e);
   }
}
start();


function filterData (data){
    document.getElementById("catList").innerHTML = `
    <select>
       <option value="Choose a cat">Choose a cat</option>
  `; // clear the list and start filling
    data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.name);
        acessArray(element.name);
    });
    document.getElementById("catList").innerHTML += '</select>'; //End

}


function acessArray(data){
    // This will add a <select> over another <select> and so on
    document.getElementById("catList").innerHTML += `
        <option> ${data} </option>            
    `;
}
```